# Toggle menu not working on smartphones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a responsive website which shows dropdown menu on smaller resolutions.Or, it should be displaying it.
There is a toggle button which jumps in on resolutions bellow 479px, but for some reason it isnt opening when clicked on it.
I am very bad with JS, so i was wondering can anyone help me.

If i understood it properly, there isnt any JS function that would "make" it open...Again, sorry, i really am not familiar with JS, still learning.

http://goo.gl/TNixQe

Thank you a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.menu_trigger').on('click', function(){
       $('nav').toggle();
   });
});
</script>
```

Just put it in your  section.

Comment: You have jQuery available. Read the docs for `.toggle()`. You can basically use the code from the examples (it's basically this answer). Also the stuff you have in main.js is completely useless. For AJAX calls you can also use jQuery (docs again).